# Scala how to write an efficient partition function?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write a very efficient partition function (lasts a line or two).

```
def insert(insertOnes: Array[String]): Array[Label] = {

    val existingOnes = this.getAll // this will get "existing" things

    //this is the hard part:
    val twoArrays = insertOnes.partition(_ != insertOnes...)

    //ignore below
    var insertSeq = scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Label]()
    for(label <- diffLabels) {
      insertSeq :+= new Label(None, label)
    }
    current.dao.Labels.insertAll(insertSeq: _*)
  }
```

This `insert` function takes in an array of Strings, and compare this array with an array of existing elements, then divide the insert elements into two arrays: one is filled with haven't been inserted elements, one is with already existing elements. I realize it is very easy to get the "different" part by calling `diff` method on array, but how do I get the "same" part of the array?

I included the `Label` case class, for the sake of completion.

```
  class Labels (tag: Tag) extends Table[Label](tag, "Labels") {
    def id = column[Option[Int]]("TAG_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def tag_name = column[String]("TAG_NAME")

    def * = (id, tag_name) <> (Label.tupled, Label.unapply _)
  }
```

Comment: An important detail has been omitted. What is the type of the insertOnes? (I think you can delete the parts that are not interesting.)

Comment: @GáborBakos `Array[String]`

Comment: I guess not...sorting String is a bit of meaningless don't you think? @GáborBakos

Comment: Well, you are looking for efficient option. On sorted arrays you can use binary search (O(log(n))), on unsorted ones your best option is linear as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you are starting from, but the solution will look something like this:

```
val existingSet = existing.toSet
val (alreadyThere, notYetThere) = insertOnes.partition(existingSet)
```

Note that a set can serve as an indicator function for filter, partition, etc.; things in the set map to `true` and things not in map to `false`.

If `existing` isn't the correct type, use `map` to extract strings that will match the input.

```
val existingSet = existing.map(_.name).toSet
```

I can't tell from your code how exactly to do this; it seems that it's probably the second argument to `Label` (which you haven't shown).

Comment: Type mismatch: expecting `(String) => Boolean` actual `Set[Label]`, but yes, you are describing exactly what I want!

Comment: Emmm..sorry if I did not ask explicitly: I encountered a type mismatch with `Set` as indicator

Comment: @WindDweller - It needs to be a `Set[String]` to work, so you will need to map the name (as described in my amended answer).

Comment: AGH! It is a bit of a problem. I'm getting the `existingSet` in a form of `List[Label]`. `Label`is a case class. Should I write an extra for loop to extract the info? Is there any way to do it faster like one line code? (I'm new to Scala but trying to do better!)

Comment: @WindDweller - Use `map`.  If the name of the field that contains the name is `name`, use exactly what I said in my answer above.  If it is something else, use the something else.  Also, "faster" and "more compactly" are **not** the same thing when it comes to programming.  "Faster" usually means "the computer can execute this faster"; "more easily" or "more compactly" refers to how much you have to type or how hard it is to think about (for you, not the computer).